# replace url of favicon using sed command is not working

Tags: sed, favicon

I  want to replace a URL present in an html file for the shortcut icon, using c. I use  sed to replace the url but the command is giving an error as it can't read the icon even if the icon is present at the specified location.

If I manually replace the URL, it's working fine.

My command is:

```
sed -i '/<link id=/c\\<link id='test' rel='shortcut icon' href='path_of_icon' type='image/x-icon'/>' path_of_html_file
```

Comment: You should use `"` instead of `'` in your regex

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "s|<link id=|<link id='test' rel='shortcut icon' href='path_of_icon' type='image/x-icon'|" path_of_html_file
```

- You use only `'` so shell mix content and interpretation
- you forget the first `s` for replacment order
- you use `/` as separtor of pattern but `/`is also in your pattern

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sed 'change' command to replace whole line containing "link id=..." then why not putting it into a script file and source via -f ? That would help with quoting issue (I believe your error is due to quoting, as already mentioned):

s.sed:

```
/<link id=/c\
<link id='test' rel='shortcut icon' href='path_of_icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
```

then

```
sed -i -f s.sed path_of_html_file
```

It's perfectly possible doing that on command line, but everything that deals with quotes inside other quotes can get pretty much ugly on a cmdline.